# How get Hidden value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to alert hidden value in this sample angularjs example. but not alert hidden value. why?

```js
function TestController($scope) {
$scope.id = "";
    $scope.test = function () {
        alert($scope.id)
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-value="12"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="test()" value="alertHiddenValue"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: that's not the correct use of `ng-value`.  According to the documentation, ng-value only binds the given expression (as a string) to the value of `<option>` or `<input type="radio>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to bind value to id using ng-model and also instead of using ng-value use ng-init to initialize it. Also as mentioned by @RGraham, if you want to have default value try to initialize it in controller.

ng-value is used for binding value to  or input [radio/checkbox], [see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

```js
function TestController($scope) {
$scope.id = "";
    $scope.test = function () {
        alert($scope.id)
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="id" ng-init="id=12"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="test()" value="alertHiddenValue"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what [ng-init should be used for](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)!

Comment: while this might work, it's not the intended use for `ng-init`, and using `ng-init` could create subtle bugs due to it's dependency on Directive Priority Ordering.

Comment: $HJZ this ***might*** work in your situation, but it isn't the **correct** way to do this; This **is not** the correct use of `ng-init`.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-value` isn't what you're looking for here. In Angular, you use `ng-model` to bind a controller value to your view element's value, like this:

```js
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.id = "12"; // Initial value can be set here
    $scope.test = function () {
        alert($scope.id);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <!-- ngModel is used to two-way bind between your value & your controller -->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="id"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="test()" value="alertHiddenValue"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i want to init hidden input in scope not in controller.